# Python Not Accepting UTF-8 Coding

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm trying to write a Python script that uses UTF-8 information, but I'm getting `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character` messages.

It looks like I can solve this by adding the following to the top of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf8
```

But I get `ascii` when I run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf8
import sys
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

Also, I've tried with the same results:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Why isn't my script using UTF-8?

Comment: The script gets the runtime encoding, the comment describes the encoding for the source. You should post an example of the code that's generating the error and the specific error, see [mcve]

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? "I'm trying to write a Python script that uses UTF-8 information" is pretty vague.

Comment: You may want to see [get encoding specified in magic line / shebang (from within module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374489/get-encoding-specified-in-magic-line-shebang-from-within-module), in which you will see that "Note that `sys.getdefaultencoding()` has *nothing* to do with how Python source code is decoded." (Martijn Pieters, 2016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it to utf-8 as:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")
```

Comment: I like this answer because it mentions a function which is frequently missed in the docs.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'` in Python 3.6