# Python 2 assumes different source code encodings

Tags: python, character-encoding, ascii, iso-8859-1, python-internals

I noticed that without source code encoding declaration, the Python 2 interpreter assumes the source code is encoded in ASCII with *scripts* and *standard input*:

```
$ python test.py  # where test.py holds the line: print u'é'
  File "test.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file test.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

$ echo "print u'é'" | python
  File "/dev/fd/63", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /dev/fd/63 on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

and it is encoded in ISO-8859-1 with the `-m` *module* and `-c` *command* flags:

```
$ python -m test  # where test.py holds the line: print u'é'
Ã©

$ python -c "print u'é'"
Ã©
```

Where is it documented?

Contrast this to Python 3 which always assumes the source code is encoded in UTF-8 and thus prints `é` in the four cases.

*Note. – I tested this on CPython 2.7.14 on both macOS 10.13 and Ubuntu Linux 17.10 with the console encoding set to UTF-8.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-c` and `-m` switches, ultimately<sup>(*)</sup> run the code supplied with the [`exec` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) or the [`compile()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile), both of which take Latin-1 source code:

> The first expression should evaluate to either a Unicode string, a *Latin-1* encoded string, an open file object, a code object, or a tuple.

This is not documented, it's an implementation detail, that may or may not be considered a bug.

I don't think it is something that is worth fixing however, and Latin-1 is a superset of ASCII so little is lost. How code from `-c` and `-m` is handled has been cleaned up in Python 3 and is much more consistent there; code passed in with  `-c` is decoded using the current locale, and modules loaded with the `-m` switch default to UTF-8, as usual.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> If you want to know the exact implementations used, start at the [`Py_Main()` function in `Modules/main.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.14/Modules/main.c#L588-L594), which handles both `-c` and `-m` as:

```c
if (command) {
    sts = PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(command, &cf) != 0;
    free(command);
} else if (module) {
    sts = RunModule(module, 1);
    free(module);
}
```

- `-c` is executed through the [`PyRun_SimpleStringFlags()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_SimpleStringFlags), which in turn calls [`PyRun_StringFlags()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_StringFlags). When you use `exec` a bytestring object is passed to `PyRun_StringFlags()` too, and the source code is then assumed to contain Latin-1-encoded bytes.
- `-m` uses the [`RunModule()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.14/Modules/main.c#L175-L209) to pass the module name to the [private function `_run_module_as_main()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.14/Lib/runpy.py#L143-L174) in the [`runpy` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html),  which uses [`pkgutil.get_loader()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_loader) to load the module metadata, and fetches the module code object with the `loader.get_code()` function on the [PEP 302 loader](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/); if no cached bytecode is available then the [code object is produced by using the `compile()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.14/Lib/pkgutil.py#L281-L283) with the mode set to `exec`.

Comment: Another thing, Python 2 documentation [states](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-interpreter-and-its-environment): "By default, Python source files are treated as encoded in UTF-8." My first test above shows that ASCII is the default, so this is a documentation error, right?

Comment: @Maggyero: oh boy, yes, that's an error in the tutorial. The language reference is the official source, see the [*Lexical Analysis* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html): *Python uses the 7-bit ASCII character set for program text.*

Comment: @Maggyero: I found the [incorrect revision](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/40ba60f6bf2f7192f86da395c71348d0fa24da09), that error was introduced recently. I've filed [a Python bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue32963) to have that corrected.